Stone-Cech compactification via lattice ideals of $Coz(X)$
While studying P. T. Johnstone's book Stone Spaces I have come across the following Proposition (Section: 3.3)

Where $max C(X)$ is the set of all maximal ideals of $C(X)$ (ring of real-valued continuous functions on a Tychonoff space $X$) and $max Coz(X)$ is the maximal ideals in the lattice $Coz(X)$ (here, $Coz(X)=\{Coz(f)\colon f\in C(X)\}$, where $Coz(f)=\{x\in X\colon f(x)\neq 0\}$).
I know that $\beta(X)$ is the index set of all ultrafilters on $X$.

Why $max Coz(X)\cong \beta X$?


Can we achieve the Stone-Cech compactification of $X$ via maximal ideals (in the lattice theoretic sense) of subsets of $X$?


It seems way more natural to instead of maximal ideals of cozero sets, to consider maximal filters of zero sets (you obtain one from another by simply taking $\mathcal{F} = {A^c : A\in I}$ if $I$ is such ideal). Then a point $p\in\beta X$ corresponds to a unique ultrafilter of zero sets that converges to $p$.

The bijection $\text{MaxSpec}(C(X))\cong \beta X$ is not only a bijection, but actually a homeomorphism if we equip the maximal spectrum with Zariski topology. The correspondence between maximal ideals $M$ of $C(X)$ and ultrafilters of zero sets is given by $M\mapsto Z(M) = {Z(f) : f\in M}$ where $Z(f) = {x\in X : f(x) = 0}$.

Yes, that is the classic Gelfand-Kolmogorov theorem. If I am not wrong. It gives us the complete characterization of maximal ideals in $C(X)$. But is it true that we can achieve $\beta X$ via maximal ideals of $Coz(X)$?

Like I said, there is a bijection between the ultrafilters of zero sets (which I'll start calling $z$-ultrafilters) and elements of $\beta X$. In fact, one construction of $\beta X$ is as a set of all $z$-ultrafilters (this mimics how one usually constructs $\beta\mathbb{N}$). But using ideals of cozero sets seems a bit awkward, since the maximal ideal corresponding to a point $p\in X$ is the set of all cozero sets that avoid $p$. You can certainly define $\beta X$ using them

As I mentioned in the comments, there is a correspondence $I\mapsto \mathcal{F}_I = \{A^c : A\in I\}$ between the maximal ideals $I$ in the lattice of cozero sets, and maximal filters $\mathcal{F}_I$ in the lattice of zero sets. The construction that seems the most natural, is not to consider ideals of cozero sets, but instead to consider filters of zero sets, or $z$-filters. Maximal $z$-filters will be called $z$-ultrafilters.
In this way we define $\beta X := \{\mathcal{F} : \mathcal{F}\text{ is a }z\text{-ultrafilter}\}$ and for each $p\in X$ we consider the $z$-ultrafilter $\mathcal{F}_p = \{Z\in Z(X) : p\in Z\}$ where $Z(X)$ is the set of all zero sets of $X$. The injection $X\hookrightarrow \beta X$ will be a Stone-Cech compactification once we define topology on $\beta X$. For each set $Z\in Z(X)$ one defines $\overline{Z} := \{\mathcal{F}\in \beta X : Z\in \mathcal{F}\}$ to be closed, and the topology on $\beta X$ is the smallest in which all of the sets $\overline{Z}$ for $Z\in Z(X)$ are closed. Then one verifies that this is indeed the Stone-Cech compactification of $X$.
The benefit of this construction is that its also easy to see the bijection $\text{MaxSpec}(C(X))\cong \beta X$ by the map $M\mapsto Z(M) = \{Z(f) : f\in M\}$ where $Z(f) = \{x\in X : f(x) = 0\}$ is the zero set of $f$, because here $Z(M)$ is a $z$-ultrafilter, so naturally an element of $\beta X$ in this construction (one can then easily verify that this is also a homeomorphism).
For details look at chapter 6 of book Rings of continuous functions by Gillman and Jerison, where all the details of this construction are verified.
Of course, by the bijection between ideals of cozero sets and filters of zero sets that I wrote above, this construction works equally well (with obvious modifications) to construct the set of all maximal ideals of cozero sets of $X$ as the Stone-Cech compactification of $X$.
